# How can I reduce the time complexity here?

Tags: segment-tree

The question states that we are given an empty list and 10^5 queries.For each query, we have two integers a and b.a can only be 1, 2 or 3.

```
if a=1, then append element b in the list.
if a=2, then add value b to every element of the list.
if a=3, then we have to print the bth smallest element in the list.
e.g. query = 5, list = []
q1 -> 1 2 -> list = [2]
q2 -> 1 4 -> list = [2,4]
q3 -> 2 5 -> list = [7,9]
q4 -> 3 1 -> print(7)
```

I have tried a brute force approach, which takes O(N logN) for each query. How can I improve this for large queries?
My brute force [link](https://ideone.com/NYByHf)

Answer (score 0):

```
elif a==2:
    for j in range(len(l)):
         l[j]+=b
```

This step can be avoided and by doing the following
`if a == 2`
     sum += b  #value ToBe Added to every element at the end of all queries at once Last

```
l=[]
query =10**5
sum = 0
for _ in range(query):
    if a==1:
        l.append(b)
    elif a==2:
        sum += b
    else:
        l.sort()
        print(l[b-1] + **sum**)
```

This can be further improved as below

```
l=[]
query =10**5
sum = 0
for _ in range(query):
    if a==1:
        // Place the element b in proper place O(n) operation increasing order
    elif a==2:
        sum += b
    else:
        print(l[b-1] + **sum**)
```

Comment: yeah but still, the time complexity is still O(q*n*log n)

Comment: `l=[]
query =10**5
sum = 0`
`for _ in range(query):`
    `if a==1:`
       `// Place the element in the proper place -> O(n) operation`
    `elif a==2:`
       ` sum += b`
   ` else:`
       ` print(l[b-1] + **sum**)`

Comment: 1st operation - O(n), 2nd operation - O(1) , 3rd operation - O(1)